# List random data from MySQL at specific time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to list random data from MySQL at a specific time - e.g. 22:00 everyday.

I'm using the following code:

```
$time = date("Ymd"); 
$sql = "SELECT id, idvideo, picture, alt FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND('$time') LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage " ;
```

How can I define this vector for a specific time? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the field name and type where the date is stored? Do you just store the time?  You should be using a WHERE clause.

Comment: The time field does not exist and the time is not stored in DB.

Comment: added tag, fixed question title and body